# R for-loop iterating from central value out to extremes

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I'm trying to improve the speed of my code, which is trying to optimise a value using 3 variables which have large ranges. The most likely output uses values in the middle of the ranges, so it is wasting time starting from the lowest possible value of each variable. I want to start from the middle value and iterate out! The actual problem has thousands of lines with numbers from 150-650. C,H and O limits will be defined somewhat based on the starting number, but will always be more likely at a central value in the defined range. Is there a way to define the for loop to work outwards like I want? The only, quite shabby, way I can think of is to simply redefine the value within the loop from a vector (e.g. 1=20, 2=21, 3=19, etc). See current code below:

```
set_error<-2.5
ct<-c(325.00214,325.00952,325.02004,325.02762,325.03535,325.03831,325.04588, 325.05641,325.06402,325.06766,325.07167,325.07454,325.10396)


FormFun<-function(x){
    for(C in 1:40){
      for(H in 1:80){
        for(O in 1:40){
        test_mass=C*12+H*1.007825+O*15.9949146-1.0072765

        error<-1000000*abs(test_mass-x)/x

        if(error<set_error){
          result<-paste("C",C,"H",H,"O",O,sep ="")
          return(result)
          break;break;break;break
        }
        }
        }
        }
}

old_t <- Sys.time()
ct2<-lapply(ct,FormFun)
new_t <- Sys.time() - old_t # calculate difference
print(new_t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use vectorization and create a [closure](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures):

```
FormFun1_fac <- function(gr) {
  gr <<- gr
  function(x, set_error){
  test_mass <- with(gr, C*12+H*1.007825+O*15.9949146-1.0072765)
  error <- 1000000 * abs(test_mass - x) / x
  ind <- which(error < set_error)[1]
  if (is.na(ind))  return(NULL)
  paste0("C", gr[ind, "C"],"H", gr[ind, "H"],"O", gr[ind, "O"])
  }
}
FormFun1 <- FormFun1_fac(expand.grid(C = 1:40, H = 1:80, O = 1:40))

ct21 <- lapply(ct, FormFun1, set_error = set_error)
all.equal(ct2, ct21)
#[1] TRUE
```

This saves a grid of all combinations of C, H, O in the function environment and calculates the error for all combinations (which is fast in vectorized code). The first combination that passes the test is returned.

Comment: Roland, I have cases where more than one row in the gr grid have error<set_error. I assume that in these cases the function either outputs the best one (lowest error) or the first one it encounters. Is there a way I can get it to delimit all cases where error<set_error (say, with / or , separation)? I would later expand the different answers into several columns

Comment: Change to `ind <- which(error < set_error)`, i.e. omit `[1]`.